# Python 3.x folium TraceBack error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, folium

I am a new user to folium, but I am trying to follow another user's code. For some reason, this isn't working and I just want to be sure it doesn't have to do with the fact that I'm using Jupyter notebook.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], tiles='cartodbpositron',
               min_zoom=1, max_zoom=4, zoom_start=1)

for i in range(0, len(full_latest)):
    folium.Circle(
        location=[full_latest.iloc[i]['Lat'], full_latest.iloc[i]['Long']],
        color='crimson', 
        tooltip =   '<li><bold>Country : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Country'])+
                    '<li><bold>Province : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Province/State'])+
                    '<li><bold>Confirmed : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Confirmed'])+
                    '<li><bold>Deaths : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Deaths'])+
                    '<li><bold>Recovered : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Recovered']),
        radius=int(full_latest.iloc[i]['Confirmed'])**1.1).add_to(m)
m
```

I am learning Data Science and checked the references to DataFrames in pandas, but don't see any errors in spelling. I've checked with my mentor, and still no luck.
Here is the Error Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4735             try:
-> 4736                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
   4737             except IndexError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4272891a2f02> in <module>
      6 for i in range(0, len(full_latest)):
      7     folium.Circle(
----> 8         location=[full_latest.iloc[i]['Lat'], full_latest.iloc[i]['Long']],
      9         color='crimson',
     10         tooltip =   '<li><bold>Country : '+str(full_latest.iloc[i]['Country'])+

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1066         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1067         try:
-> 1068             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1069 
   1070             if not is_scalar(result):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4742                     raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   4743                 else:
-> 4744                     raise e1
   4745             except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
   4746                 raise e1

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4728         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
   4732             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Lat'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to reference a 'Lat', which is not in the dataset I am using. Apologies for the question spam.